# Load the last played scene where user lost instead of loading the start scene all over again, Unity Block breaker game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I have made block breaker game in unity 4.6 and i have added 3 levels. If anyone loses in any level say level_02 then the lose screen showing game over loads up. When he clicks try again it loads the start screen as i have  ordered them in my build settings. I want my game to load the same level where the user have lost so that he clicks try again and the same level loads again i.e level_02.

Comment: is it one scene one level?

Comment: there are 3 scenes for 3 levels

Answer (score 1):

You can save the current levelScene name before you loads the looseScene like,

```
PlayerPrefs.SetString("LastLevelName",ScaneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
```

and when you click the restart button in looseScene then call some method like this,

```
public void RestartSameLevel(){
    SceneManager.LoadScene(PlayerPrefs.GetString("LastLevelName","DefaultSceneName");
    //"DefaultSceneName" can be your StartScene name
}
```

Comment: "LastLevelName" it could be any of 3 levels. if user loses at level_03 lets say so how to redirect him to the level_03 again?

Comment: Yes it could be any of your 3 levels, that's why we are saving last level scene name using 
`SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name` with a key "LastLevelName" in PlayerPrefs.

Answer (score 0):

You can restart the scene

```
Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel)
```

Or

```
Scene scene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene(); 
SceneManager.LoadScene(scene.name);
```

Comment: does not work, following error:    Cannot load scene: Invalid scene name (empty string) and invalid build index -1
UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager:LoadScene(String)
LevelManager:LastLevel() (at Assets/Scripts/LevelManager.cs:31)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update()